# vim: How to subsitute forward-slash,asterisk, and left curly bracket?

Tags: vim

In vim, when I do `echo substitute("/*{","/*{","","g")`, it prints out `/*`.  Even escaping all the characters (`echo substitute("\/\*\{","\/\*\{","","g")`) results in `/*`.

I just want to replace `/*{` with a zero-length.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I'm an idiot.  I needed to escape only the asterisk in the {pat} portion of the expression.  I was in the mindset that the second field was just a {string} field, not a {pattern} field -- so I wasn't even thinking about pattern matching.

So, the answer is:

`echo substitute("/*{","/\*{","","g")`